# jQuery click first x number of buttons

Tags: jquery, while-loop

```
tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']:first").click();
```

This, along with my other code, will click every "selecteren" button, however I only want to click the first X number of buttons.

```
var numberoftimes = 5
```

So each time it clicks maybe count? Of something like that, and while count <= numberoftimes, keep clcking.

I don't really know how to do something like this =/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: @CBroe, you should add that as an answer. It's way cleaner than the loops.

Comment: CBroe is right, the `lt` selector is what you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/DB34u/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:lt` as CBroe pointed out in the comments

```
tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']:lt(" + numberoftimes + ")").click();
```

this will click first five buttons

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/DB34u/)

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector)

Comment: I had never even heard of that. Great stuff! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a for loop:

```
var buttons = tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']");
var numberoftimes = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < numberoftimes; i++) {
    $(buttons[i]).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using http://api.jquery.com/each/ :

```
tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']").each(function(index){
    if(index<5) { $(this).trigger('click'); }
});
```

Keep in mind that the index is zero-indexed.

If speed is a big issue, you could add `} else { return false; }` to stop the loop.